# Kafka + Spark Streaming - spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition breached

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a streaming application that has been running for around a week now.  I set up `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` to limit the rate of record digestion.

I understand that the application should effectively receive at most `batch-interval-seconds * spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition * partitions` per batch.

This was working great for days, and the load quite often spiked up to that maximum value.  Then, all of the sudden, the application breached that maximum by around 50% after a series of 0-record batches.

**So, a few questions:**

1. Under what conditions may spark/kafka ignore spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition?
2. Does back-pressure help to mitigate this issue?  I have trouble understanding back-pressure as if you have a maximum rate `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` you shouldn't have spikes you weren't prepared for.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you find how to prevent that?

Comment: I never found out why it was possible, but the issue went away after tuning to have more executors with less cores and memory which made the process generally faster and more stable.  I also set up a detection mechanism that would call the yarn api to kill the job and restart it in case it ever acted up.